# Can I bring together all packages in one \usepackage{} command?

Tags: packages

I have many `\usepackage{}` commands in the preamble of `Thesis.tex`. Can I bring them together into one `\usepackage{}` command. Is there any limitation for the number of packages in case of such usage? Also may a conflict occur when one uses packages together?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I don't recommend it -- it's not really user friendly to read a long list of packages and besides that, some of them have options

Comment: You are right, but I want to minimize the number of rows in the preamble. Is there any other option?

Comment: you can load as many packages as you like with one call of `\usepackage` as long as those packages don't need any options. Since this seems to be your private file you also don't have to care if others find it easy to read or not as long as you're comfortable with it.

Comment: If you just want to minimize the number of rows, consider using a single line such as `\usepackage{abc} \usepackage{def} ...`. This allows people to use a text-based find function to look for `\usepackage{abc}` (or at least, with options, `{abc}`). For example, in a document using a lot of `\times`, this allows to quickly determine whether the `times` packages has been loaded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your `\usepackage{}` commands don't contain options (like `\usepackage[option]{package}`, you can easily combine them like this: `\usepackage{package1,package2,package3}` and so on.

This has no functional difference to listing them all in their own line, and IIRC there should not be a limit on how many packages you can put into one `\usepackage` command.